# Кормен "Алгоритмы": найти время работы алгоритма сортировки выборкой

Tags: алгоритм

Тут есть такая задача - найти время работы алгоритма сортировки выборкой. И тут возникает вопрос, какие средства доступны юзеру при написании сего алгоритма, ведь если имеется возможность использовать списки, время будет O(n), ибо мы можем, не проводя нудную операцию сдвига всего массива на один элемент, вставить в начало, а если нет - O(n^2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы что-то путаете явно. Сортировка выбором не сдвигает элементы массива, она их меняет местами.

```
2 4 7 3 5 1 - исходный массив
1 4 7 3 5 2 - 1 минимальный, меняем 1 и 2
1 2 7 3 5 4 - 2 минимальный, меняем 2 и 4
1 2 3 7 5 4
1 2 3 4 7 5
1 2 3 4 5 7
```

Независимо от структуры данных операций сравнения будет O(n^2)